# Shopware 6: Which event should I subscribe to get all variants of the product on the Home Page?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

There is a slider on the homepage where the products are listed. Here I want to show the colors of the variants that the products have. Which event should I subscribe to get all variants of the product on the Home Page?

Answer (score 0):

You could decorate the CMS element resolver. You'll need to inject the repository of the configurator settings, as you won't be able to get all variants from the resolved product, as it will be one of the variants and only the actual parent has associations to all variants.

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Product\Cms\ProductSliderCmsElementResolverDecorator" decorates="Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Cms\ProductSliderCmsElementResolver">
    <argument type="service" id="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Product\Cms\ProductSliderCmsElementResolverDecorator.inner"/>
    <argument type="service" id="product_configurator_setting.repository"/>
</service>
```

```php
class ProductSliderCmsElementResolverDecorator implements CmsElementResolverInterface
{
    private CmsElementResolverInterface $decorated;

    private EntityRepositoryInterface $productConfiguratorSettingRepository;

    public function __construct(
        CmsElementResolverInterface $decorated,
        EntityRepositoryInterface $productConfiguratorSettingRepository
    ) {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
        $this->productConfiguratorSettingRepository = $productConfiguratorSettingRepository;
    }

    public function getType(): string
    {
        return $this->decorated->getType();
    }

    public function collect(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext): ?CriteriaCollection
    {
        return $this->decorated->collect($slot, $resolverContext);
    }

    public function enrich(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext, ElementDataCollection $result): void
    {
        $this->decorated->enrich($slot, $resolverContext, $result);

        // results from product streams
        $entitySearchResult = $result->get('product-slider-entity-fallback_' . $slot->getUniqueIdentifier());
        if ($entitySearchResult === null) {
            // manual results
            $entitySearchResult = $result->get('product-slider_' . $slot->getUniqueIdentifier());
        }
        if ($entitySearchResult === null) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var ProductEntity $product */
        foreach ($entitySearchResult->getElements() as $product) {
            if (!$product->getParentId()) {
                continue;
            }

            $criteria = new Criteria();
            $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('productId', $product->getParentId()));
            $criteria->addAssociation('option.group');

            $configuratorSettings = $this->productConfiguratorSettingRepository->search(
                $criteria,
                $resolverContext->getSalesChannelContext()->getContext()
            )->getElements();

            $variants = [];
            /** @var ProductConfiguratorSettingEntity $configuratorSetting */
            foreach ($configuratorSettings as $configuratorSetting) {
                $variants[$configuratorSetting->getOption()->getGroup()->getName()][] = $configuratorSetting->getOption()->getName();
            }

            $product->addExtension('variantsArray', new ArrayStruct($variants));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the template you can use the extension for those products that have variants.

```html
{% if product.extensions.variantsArray is defined %}
    <ul>
        {% for group, values in product.extensions.variantsArray.all() %}
            <li>
                {{ group }}:
                {% for value in values %}
                    {{ value }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, also how can I get the photo and url of the variants?

`$criteria = new Criteria();$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('productId', $product->getParentId()));$criteria->addAssociations(['options', 'options.group', 'options.media', 'cover']);` 

I tried this way but I couldn't get the data.

Comment: I changed product_configurator_setting.repository to product.repository in services.xml. So I can access all the data about the product, cover, url etc. Thanks again.